# I'm a bit confused about function notation and range/domain

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Given the function $$f :[-a,3a) \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = 2a - x $$where $a ∈ \mathbb{R}^+$, then the range of the function of *f* is:

My working out so far

$$f(x) = 2a - (-a)$$
$$  = 3a$$

$$f(x) = 2a - 3a = -a$$

So would that mean the range of the function is the same as the domain?

Comment: No. Do you know how to use MathJax to format the math expressions?

Comment: @Yuki.F No unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close - be careful since your domain is $[-a, 3a)$. Remember that we can't actually input $3a$ into our function and thus $-a$ isn't actually in the range of our function. But, we can certainly say that our range is instead $(-a, 3a]$. How would we rigorously prove this? Well, suppose $x$ is an element of our domain. That is, suppose $-a \leq x < 3a$. Multiplying these inequalities by $-1$, we have $ -3a < -x \leq a$. Then, if we add $2a$ to everything, we obtain $-a < 2a -x \leq 3a$. But that $2a-x$ in the middle is precisely $f(x)$, so we have shown $ -a < f(x) \leq 3a$ holds for all $x$ in our domain. So our range, denote it by $R$, is a subset of $(-a, 3a]$. To show the reverse inclusion, suppose $y \in (-a, 3a]$. That is, $-a < y \leq 3a$. Then, by manipulating these inequalities in a similar manner as done previously, one can show that $2a-y$ is an element of our domain (i.e. $-a \leq 2a - y < 3a$ holds) and clearly $f(2a-y) = y$. Hence, $(-a, 3a] \subset R$ which implies $R = (-a, 3a]$.

Comment: Thank you for this! It's been very helpful :)